# Inequality involving $x^2+y^2+z^2 =3$

Tags: inequality

If  $ x^2+y^2+z^2 =3 $ prove that :

$3(x+y+z)\ge 3+xy+yz+xz+x^2y+y^2z+z^2x $

Comment: You have to have $x,y,z \ge 0$.?

Comment: Yes they are. !

Answer (score 3):

I found it may be easy with Lagrange multiplier:

$f=3(x+y+z)-(3+xy+yz+xz+x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)$

$g=\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2 -3)$

let $F=3(x+y+z)-(3+xy+yz+xz+x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)+\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2 -3)$

```
EDIT: I had a mistake when did partial which pointed out by Ivan, so I correct it. the case will be a little complex but calculation is a little simple.
```

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 3-(y+z+2xy+z^2)+2\lambda x=0$...........<1>

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 3-(x+z+2yz+x^2)+2\lambda y=0$...........<2>

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z} = 3-(x+y+2xz+y^2)+2\lambda z=0$...........<3>

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda} = x^2+y^2+z^2 -3=0  $....................<4>

<1>-<2>: $(x-y)(1+\lambda)+(z-x)(2y-x-z)=0$........<5>

<2>-<3>: $(y-z)(1+\lambda)+(x-y)(2z-x-y)=0$........<6>

<1>-<3>: $(z-x)(1+\lambda)+(y-z)(2x-y-z)=0$........<7>

It is clear that $x=y=z$ is one solution for <5><6><7> no matter what $\lambda$ is. so we will not discuss this case anymore.

now we discuss $\lambda$:

if $\lambda=-1$, we will have :

$(z-x)(2y-x-z)=0$......<8>

$(x-y)(2z-x-y)=0$......<9>

$(y-z)(2x-y-z)=0$......<10>

and WLOG, we have two cases:

case I: $x=y\not = z $,then from <10>  $(y-z)^2=0$  that is: $y=z$, it is impossible.

case II: none of $x,y,x$ equals each other, then we will have:

$(2y-x-z)=0$......<11>

$(2z-x-y)=0$......<12>

$(2x-y-z)=0$......<13>

but we still get x=y=z. that is impossible also. so this case is not OK.

if $\lambda \not= -1$, WLOG, we can have another 2 cases:

caseI: none of $x,y,x$ equals each other, let $x>y>z$ then we will have:
$ \dfrac{(x-y)(2z-x-y)}{z-y}=\dfrac{(y-z)(2x-y-z)}{x-z}$......<14>  (from<6>and <7>)

$\dfrac{(y-z)(2x-y-z)}{x-z}=\dfrac{(z-x)(2y-x-z)}{y-x} $......<15> (from<5>and<6>)

let $u=x-y>0 ,v=y-z >0,w=z-x <0$, then $w=-(u+v)$, put in <14> and <15>, we get:

$v^3-uv^2-3vu^2-u^3=0$......<16>

$v^3-3vu^2-u^3=0$......<17>

<16>-<17>,we have $uv^2=0$, that is , $u=0$ or $v=0$, which is impossible. so this case is not possible.

case II: $x=y\not=z$

from<6>, we have $(y-z)(1+\lambda)=0$, if $y-z\not=0,$, that is $1+\lambda=0$, which is impossible as we already set $1+\lambda \not=0$. so this case is also impossible.

To summary above case, we have only one case is OK, that is:$x=y=z=1$

To verify it, put $x=y=0,z=\sqrt{3}$ in $f, f=3\sqrt{3}>0$,

so $f_{min}=0$, when $x=y=z=1$

QED.

Comment: Nice. I don't know why I haven't thought of using Lagrange multiplier. It's a natural way to think of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cauchy Schwarz inequality. This is a hint!

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong of course! Try $x=y=z=-1$.

But this inequality is true for non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$.

Indeed, let $\{x,y,z\}=\{a,b,c\}$, where $a\geq b\geq c$.

Hence, by Rearrangement and AM-GM we obtain:
$$x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+xyz=x\cdot xy+y\cdot tz+z\cdot zx+abc\leq a\cdot ab+b\cdot ac+c\cdot bc+abc=$$
$$=b(a+c)^2=4b\left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2\leq4\left(\frac{a+\frac{b+c}{2}+\frac{b+c}{2}}{3}\right)^3=\frac{4(a+b+c)^3}{27}=\frac{4(x+y+z)^3}{27}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$3(x+y+z)\geq3+xy+xz+yz+\frac{4(x+y+z)^3}{27}-xyz$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}x^2\sum_{cyc}x-\frac{4(x+y+z)^3}{27}+xyz\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^2+xy)\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}}.$$
Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove a linear inequality of $w^3$, which says that

it's enough to prove the last inequality for an extremal value of $w^3$,

which happens in the following cases.

1.$w^3=0$.

Let $z=0$ and $y=1$.

We need to prove that 
$$(x+1)(x^2+1)-\frac{4(x+1)^3}{27}\geq(x^2+1+x)\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{3}}.$$
Let $x^2+1=2ux$.

Hence, $u\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$(2u+2)\left(2u-\frac{8(u+1)}{27}\right)^2\geq\frac{2}{3}u(2u+1)^2$$ or
$$1144u^3+408u^2-915u+64\geq0,$$
which is obvious for $u\geq1$;

2. $y=z=1$, which gives
   $$(x-1)^2(143x^4+490x^3+588x^2+994x+701)\geq0.$$
   Done!